# Заблокировать telegtam мессенждер в сети

Tags: linux, telegram, mikrotik, firewall, pfsense

Был ли у кого-нибудь удачный опыт блокировки telegram в сети используя mitrotik/pfsense/linux или каким-то другим способом?

Comment: Хотите потягаться с Роскомнадзором? ;-)

Comment: в локальном сегменте можно попробовать заблочить всё кроме хттп/хттпс

Comment: @Oxyd а вдруг это сотрудник Роскомнадзора?)

Comment: @eri от этого телеграм уже изобрёл специальные прокси, которые маскируются под хттпс

Comment: @andreymal и там скорее всего пропущенно sni или сертификаты прокси имеют CN определеного вида.

Comment: @eri в sni прописывают google.com для маскировки (да и esni уже существует), а насчёт сертификатов чёт не помню

Comment: Так если пишут google.com, то можно это завайтлистить на подсети гугла.

Comment: А esni можно отфильтровать в dns. Запретив всё днс кроме локального

Comment: А DoH, там, телеграм ещё не научился?

Comment: @Oxyd идея в том чтобы все пользовались корпоративный чатом - rocketchat и все переписка хранилась в компании, так как много секретной информации.

Comment: пока я нашел информацию про squid - https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Chat/Telegram, но не хотелось бы узнать опыт реальных людей, которое это реализовывали

Comment: @eri нашел старую статью как это можно через api telegtam + squid сделать https://yvoinov.blogspot.com/2019/04/naked-king-or-how-to-ban-telegram.html Не знаю актуальна она сейчас или нет

Comment: @picapica У вас пользователи имеют право устанавливать софт?

Comment: @Oxyd, смысла в вопросе не особо, учитывая, что телега ставится в профиль пользователя.

Comment: @don Rumata в качестве теста я заблокировал через gpo запуск telegram.exe, это работает, до момента, когда пользователь догадается переименовать telegram.exe

Comment: Может тогда блочить по sha1 хэшу бинарника?

Comment: При наличае у сотрудников доступа к 4G/LTE любые блокировки идут лесом если вы не обыскиваете и изымаете все средствамсва связи.

Comment: По трафику suricata -> pfsense можно создовать роли